# Using AM and PM with time in overloaded constructors, JAVA

Tags: java

Ok so I have been trying to create a very simple clock display using overloaded constructors, where I use void main string to create 4 different objects each with specific times. It seems hard to explain but below you can see my Main class and another class.

```
public class fancyTimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        fancyTime ft1 = new fancyTime(10, 30, 25);
        displayTime("fancyTime 1", ft1);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("%nError: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }


        try {
        fancyTime ft2 = new fancyTime(13, 22);
        displayTime("fancyTime 2", ft2);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("%nError: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }


        try {
        fancyTime ft3 = new fancyTime(23, 5, 10);
        displayTime("fancyTime 3", ft3);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("%nError: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }


        try {
        fancyTime ft4 = new fancyTime(8, 30, 43);                   
        displayTime("fancyTime 4", ft4);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("%nError: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }   
    }



    public static void displayTime(String header, fancyTime t) {
        if (t.getFlag() == 1) {
            System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n \n", header, t.toStandardString());
        }

        if (t.getFlag() == 2) {
            System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n \n", header, t.toUniversalString());
        }

        if (t.getFlag() == 3) {
            System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n \n", header, t.toUniversalShortString());
        }    
    }

}
```

As you can see each of the 4 'fancyTime's have different arguments. Now below, you can see how i'm trying to use overloaded constructors to be able to read the different arguments in the Main class.

Problem is every time i run this, it returns "Error: can only be 'AM' or 'PM'

```
public class fancyTime {

    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    private String meridiem;
    private int flag;

    public fancyTime() {
        this(0);
    }

    public fancyTime(int hour) {
        this(hour, 0);
    }

    public fancyTime(int hour, int minute) {
        this(hour, minute, 0);
    }


    public fancyTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        this(hour, minute, second, " ");

    }

    public fancyTime(int hour, int minute, int second, String meridiem) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour is not between 0-23");
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute is not between 0-59");
        if (second < 0 || second >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second is not between 0-59");
        if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only be 'AM' or 'PM'");

    }


    public void setHour(int hour) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-23");

        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute must be 0-59");

        this.minute = minute;
    }

    public void setSecond(int second) {
        if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second must be 0-59");

        this.second = second;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }


    public String toStandardString() {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour ==0 || hour ==12) ? 12 : hour % 12), minute, second, (hour <12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
    }

    public String toUniversalString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", this.hour, this.minute, this.second);
    }

    public String toUniversalShortString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", this.hour, this.minute);
    }
}
```

Any help would be so appreciated and please go easy as I am only new

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement will always throw exception regardless of `meridiem` value.

[DEMO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaWFCMG1tWFNoR0k)

*test case 1*

```
meridiem = "AM";

if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM"))
if (!true || !false)
if (false || true)
if (true) --> throws exception
```

*test case 2*

```
meridiem = "PM";

if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM"))
if (!false || !true)
if (true || false)
if (true) --> throws exception
```

*test case 3*

```
meridiem = "something else";

if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM"))
if (!false || !false)
if (true || true)
if (true) --> throws exception
```

---

Your should instead change it to:

```
if (!(meridiem.equals("AM") || meridiem.equals("PM")))
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only be 'AM' or 'PM'");
```

[DEMO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcDJwVS1MREVYeXM)